# Light leaks all over the photos

Tags: film, 35mm, fujifilm, light-leaks

It is my first time using a film camera and I've developed my first roll of film, Lomography CN 400. The camera is a  Fujifilm MDL-9.

I know that my problem is light leaks and it's coming from the back of the camera (*i think*), but the fact that there are so many horizontal lines of it in some photos that I took makes me confused about where's is the leak that caused it.

[image]

[Link to full size image](https://ibb.co/wsCVjJ1)

Here are the back side of my camera:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried shooting a roll after covering the back window with black (gaffer) tape?

Comment: As this is my first time, no, but I've already covered the back window of my camera with tape and I'm going to see the result after I send the roll to a lab.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/90364/these-slr-developed-photos-are-bad-is-it-mine-or-the-photolabs-fault/90366#90366

Comment: I thought the entire point of most Lomography products was to create "unique" images due to defects such as light leaks or uncorrected lens aberrations?

Answer (score 2):

Find a tiny key-chain flashlight that remains on without the need to keep pressing the button. This flashlight must be small enough to fit in the camera with no film loaded and the back closed. Turn on flashlight and close film loading door. Find the darkest room in your home, likely a closet or bath. Cover all cracks under and around the door with towels. The idea is total darkness. Best you do this at night with all adjacent lights off.

Retire with the camera to this dark place and sit with the camera. It likely will take 15 minutes for your eyes to dark-adapt. During this wait time, examine the camera from all angles. This theory "if light leaks in, it will also leak out". This flashlight trick works, but you must be in total darkness and dark-adapted. This takes 15 to 20 minutes. Your eyes gain sensitivity by secreting a chemical nicknamed "visible violet" which bathes the retina and increases the eye's ISO.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'll try that when I get one in my hand.