# Light leaks on OM10

Tags: light-leaks

I recently ran a roll of Kodak 400TX through an OM10.  Some of the roll appeared to be fine but many of the images showed vertical light leaks - the attached is the best(worst) example of this. Any ideas as to where the leaks may be coming from?

Bryan

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, searching for 'olympus om10' the first hits are for replacement light seals ;)

Comment: Take a look also at this Q&A: [These SLR developed photos are bad. Is it mine or the photolab's fault?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90364)

Answer (score 4):

Because the light comes from the top of the picture, it is leaking in from the bottom of the camera (unless you were holding the camera upside down in which case the leak is at the top of the camera). It is not coming through the viewfinder (because the viewfinder is at the top of the camera)[1]. As mentioned, the most probable fix is replacing the light seals. There is probably a Youtube video that will help you do it yourself if you don't want to pay someone to do it.

[1]: unless you were holding the camera upside down.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the film via black light. Do you see darker streaks stemming from film sprocket holes? Could be caused by improper loading or unloading of film or improper developing.

Anyway, to rule out camera light leak, procure a tiny keychain flashlight that stays on when switched. Insert lighted flash light into camera and close the back. Now retire to fully dark darkroom. Sit with the camera a minimum of 20 minutes, This time allows time for your eyes to dark adapt. Look at the camera from all angles. Light that leaks in, also leaks out.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking closely at the image.  There is a solid and consistent vertical bar on the right side.  It does not vary in width or intensity from top to bottom.  That looks like a sluggish shutter curtain - OR - It may be from a processing reel.  The light leaks also look more like a processing issue than a film door issue.   Did you process the film yourself?

Comment: This does not answer the question. It provides an observation, A few guesses and then asks a question, It does not answer the OP’s question. This should be posted in the comments section as it does not provide an answer.

Comment: I did answer the question.    What is your problem?