# Is this a light leak

Tags: scanning, olympus, light-leaks

I received a Olympus Mju 1 recently and ran a test role.

My scans are showing orange lines to the side as well as circles.

I am very very new to the world of film photography and am thinking maybe it’s a linger leak and I should look at getting the seals checked. That being said, very conscious it could be operator error!

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: For me look like flare: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare

Comment: Very suspicious that is the same light in totally different images. Could it be a broken led to imprint a date on images? Does that camera feature such thing?

Comment: Nope - no date stamps on it so can hopefully rule that out

Answer (score 2):

Imho, yes it is a light leak. But it is a bit weird because the sphere is very focused.

But the pattern is somehow repeated. Is this the same leak?

[image]

So it is a bit confusing where it is coming from. We could make a better guess seeing the negatives. If the pattern is from consecutive photos or it is across different ones and how it fades across the roll.

I posted some very general examples of different sources of light leaks here: [These SLR developed photos are bad. Is it mine or the photolab's fault?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/90364/these-slr-developed-photos-are-bad-is-it-mine-or-the-photolabs-fault/90366#90366)

So the pattern across the roll is important to determine the source.

Comment: Maybe there's a light leak at the 'film canister window' ? that would localize things. Also the other light seals look like they might be felt instead of foam.